# jQuery remove only works on the second click after an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have two divs each with a list of links, when a link is clicked an AJAX call is made which appends some JSON data to a separate div. At the same time as the data is appended I want the div with the links where the link that was just clicked to be hidden/removed.

There is a third div with the class "panel-close" that can be clicked which removes the div with data that was just appended and makes the div containing the links reappear again. So everything is back to the original state

The problem I'm having is that once the div containing the data has been removed sometimes the div containing the links does not appear again, sometimes it happens on a second click of the panel close div and sometimes the JSON data does not append again after clicking on a link.

My is the basic set up of my HTML:

```
<div class="curation-panel">
 <div class="curation-contents-list">
   <a class="load-article"></a>
 </div>

 <div class="article-container">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="film-panel">
 <div class="film-contents-list">
   <a class="load-project"></a>
 </div>

 <div class="project-container">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-close">
</div>
```

I'm a Jquery noob, I've probably taken completely the wrong approach but this is my jquery code:

```
$(function(){
  var element = $('.load-article');
  var url     = element.data('page') + '.json';
  var target  = $('.article-container');

  $(element).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.get(url, function(data) {
      $('.curation-contents-list').hide();
      $(target).append(data);
    });
      $("body").addClass("load-article-is-open"),
      $(this).animate({
          scrollTop: 0
      }, 300, "easeInOutExpo")

  });
}),

$(function(){
  var element = $('.load-project');
  var url     = element.data('page') + '.json';
  var target  = $('.project-container');

  $('.load-project').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.get(url, function(data) {
      $('.film-contents-list').hide();
        $(target).append(data);
    });
      $("body").addClass("load-project-is-open"),
        $(this).animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 300, "easeInOutExpo")
  });
}),

$(".panel-close").click(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("curation-panel-is-open").removeClass("film-panel-is-open").removeClass("load-article-is-open").removeClass("load-project-is-open"),
    $(".curation-panel").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 300, "easeInOutExpo"),
    $(".film-panel").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 300, "easeInOutExpo"),

    $('.curation-contents').show();
    $('.film-contents-list').show();
    $('.article-container').remove();
    $('.project-container').remove();
});
```

Comment: future reference, there is no reason to do  `$(element).on`, it is already a jQuery object so you can just do  `element.on`. Just a pointer, not going to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, it's duly noted

Answer (score 1):

You reference an element which you than append the results of the Ajax call to

```
var target  = $('.article-container');
```

And the problem here is the fact you are removing the elements

```
$('.article-container').remove();
$('.project-container').remove();
```

After you remove them, the code that references them can not find them.

I think you want to use `empty()` and not `remove()`

Comment: thank you, that makes a lot of sense, I should've realised. The only problem I have now is that when I load the page it takes a second click of the `.panel-close` to empty the div containing the data and to show the list that contains the div. After that it works fine.